# jsFiddle jQuery working ... not working on localhost

Tags: jquery, click, toggle

I have a bit of an issue, been trying to get my head round it for quite some time now. Searched through a lot of topics but haven't found anything that helps me out.

I edited a jsFiddle that I found and designed this simple Toggle navigation:

http://jsfiddle.net/liamtarpey/GzkN4/

Only problem is, I've tried to now integrate it into my website but it's not working, I've cut it down to just a test page to try and figure out the problem but still no luck. I'm using WAMP server to test and all my php and other javascript things work fine.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>jQuery Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script> 
    </head>

<body>

    <div class="alt-nav">
        <h3>Menu</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="press.php">Press</a></li>
                <li><a href="gigs.php">Gigs</a></li>
                <li><a href="music.php">Music</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="videos.php">Videos</a></li>
                <li><a href="shop.php">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the external .js file

script.js :

```
$('.alt-nav').click(function() {
        $('ul').slideToggle(550, 'linear');
});?
```

and finally CSS:

```
.alt-nav {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;     
    border-bottom: 2px solid #F06;
}
.alt-nav h3, ul {
    color: white;
}
.alt-nav ul {
    display: none;
}
```

(the ul can be none or just removed, they both should work, this should just hide it on page load).

Thing is it looks fine in the browser but it just does not work, It's completely static as if it's not reading the script whatsoever.

Could someone please help me out with this issue?

Any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the developer tools console to see if all your scripts are being loaded and if any errors are occurring?

Comment: I forgot to mention, my index is actually index.php - I don't beleive it causes an issue that it's not saved as a .html file, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Use sitesucker (sitesucker.us) to download this page: http://jsfiddle.net/liamtarpey/GzkN4/show/result/

Comment: Or try this: http://jsfiddle.net/GzkN4/17/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an invalid URL for jQuery.

If you want to use the Google CDN, use //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: This the right answer. The jQuery lib referenced by the asker was returning a 404...

Answer (score 0):

You can defer your script until window.onload to make sure jQuery is loaded before your script is executed.

```
<script defer="defer" type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the fast replies! I've tried the options:

1. unfortunately "defer" doesn't make any difference
2. tried adding http:// to the google library but it still doesn't find it - then tried downloading the .min file - doesn't work either
3. I get the following errors in the developer tools console:

GET http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymin.js 404 (Not Found) index.php:7
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ? script.js:3

Comment: Make sure that `?` is not in your `script.js` file, and try putting `http://` infront of the jQuery call.

Comment: unfortunately it's still the same.

Comment: @Laurence The ? definitely may be the issue. The http:// isn't necessary because // automatically resolved https or http.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the '?' as suggested but there's no change at all. Possibly a WAMP issue?

Answer (score 0):

your `script.js` is being loaded **before** your document is ready.

Comment: Thanks, where would you recommend I place it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your script in `script.js` in a `$(document).ready()` call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // or $(function(){
    $('.alt-nav').click(function() {
        $('ul').slideToggle(550, 'linear');
    });
});
```

Here is the jQuery API page about `.ready()`: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Hi, thanks I edited the file but it didn't make any difference on the user end :(

Comment: Your jQuery api path is not resolving. Try `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

remove `?` symbol from your js file at the end of ready function. Script will work fine for you
Place you code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script.js is loaded before your document is known to the DOM parser. 
So your selector **$('.alt-nav')** returns *null*, and this is why your event is not happening: it is bound to a null object. You need to place your script.js include statement after the body tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>jQuery Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymin.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>
    </head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script> 
    <div class="alt-nav">
        <h3>Menu</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="press.php">Press</a></li>
                <li><a href="gigs.php">Gigs</a></li>
                <li><a href="music.php">Music</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="videos.php">Videos</a></li>
                <li><a href="shop.php">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Also, remove that ? at the end of script.js

Comment: Many thanks, I've taken out the '?' and placed the statement where you advised but still no joy.

Comment: I assure you, if you run that code with a working jQuery, it **will** work. http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymin.js returns a 404 error.